# Change the minus image and action when UITableView is in edit mode

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have two questions:

**Can we change the tap event of the (-) minus sign that appears when the table is in editmode?**

**Can we change the image of the minus sign that appears when the table is in edit mode?**

I tried to find the solution in various posts but failed. So if you know the solution in any other post kindly paste the link over here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the minus sign image, but if you are using it to actually delete items then I would recommend that you keep it as it is anyway.  The reason is that it is a well-known icon to iPhone users.  If you want to represent delete in some other way, it may be potentially confusing.

That said, if you want the left button to represent something else, then you can create a custom table cell with an image on the left.  That image can be anything you want then.  You can display or hide the custom icon by overriding didTransitionToState:

Comment: Hey Chris Thanks for reply.
I dont want to perform the deletion operation.. I just want to show the minus sign. which when clicked does nothing.. (not even change itself to (|) sign... And I have tried creating a custom cell but can u tell how we can change the width of the cell? In editing mode the cell itself changes its width.. i want that width by default. And simple minus image before the cell. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [Chris Carrett](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973652/672989)

> You can't change the minus sign image, but if you are using it to actually delete items then I would recommend that you keep it as it is anyway. The reason is that it is a well-known icon to iPhone users. If you want to represent delete in some other way, it may be potentially confusing.

However if you really want to change the icon you could try to remove it and add your own UIImageView in place.

**Update:**
I struggled with this but think I finally got it right.

I made a github repo as an example but this is the code hiding the old image:

```
- (void) removeOriginalEditControl{
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellEditControl"]) {
            for (UIView *subsubview in subview.subviews) {
                if ([NSStringFromClass([subsubview class]) isEqualToString:@"UIImageView"]) {
                    [subsubview removeFromSuperview];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Check out the full example at: https://github.com/tiemevanveen/TableViewCustomEditControls